# Does Google App Engine and Google Drive work in China?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-drive-api, great-firewall-of-china

Does Google App Engine and Google Drive work in China?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming

Answer (score 1):

Google App Engine doesn't working from China (China is known for its democracy ;) ).
Here is a link to help you to bypass the problem: http://www.haohaoreport.com/general/google-app-engine-blocked-in-china-and-solution